# Error in File Class?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6

I have a button at the stage of the name "butdin" And add him as the class : I want to when you press the Menu button in the file show Why button does not work..

```
package {
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.system.fscommand;
import flash.media.SoundMixer;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.StageScaleMode;

import fl.display.ProLoader;

import flash.system.fscommand;

import fl.video.FLVPlayback;

import flash.display.StageAlign;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

import fl.controls.List;

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.DisplayObjectContainer;
import flash.display.SimpleButton;
import flash.display.Graphics;
import flash.display.Shape;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.display.SimpleButton;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.MovieClip;

import fl.controls.Button;

import flash.display.SimpleButton;

public class butdin extends SimpleButton {
    butdin.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, sayit);
    public function sayit(e : MouseEvent) : void {
        var list : List = new List();
        list.setSize(361, 291);
        list.move(421, 254);
        var i : uint;
        for (i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
            list.addItem({label:"Track " + i});
        }
        list.addItem({label:"Track 1"});
        list.addItem({label:"Track 2"});
        list.addItem({label:"Track 3"});
        list.addItem({label:"Track 4"});
        list.addItem({label:"Track 5"});
        list.addItem({label:"Track 6"});
        list.addItem({label:"Track 7"});
        addChild(list);
    }
    list.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, itemClick);
    public function itemClick() {
        status_txt.text = "You selected: " + event.target.selectedItem.label;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: first why you need so much imports inside a button?This code is not going to work anyway. Please give more details about what you really want.

Comment: @harilalkm I do not know predicted problem there .. I try my resolve the problem

Comment: still i can't understand what you are saying.

Comment: is this class "butdin " associated to a button or any other displayobject?

Comment: @harilalkm I want to add a button when pressed .. drop-down list of some of the titles show .. when pressed on the title opens me SWF file outside

Comment: so where you added this butdin class? as document class ?

Comment: @harilalkm ..How to connect button to create a file xml for a drop-down list "tree menu" in AS3 [Like this](http://boulderapps.co/post/tree-menu-with-actionscript-as3)  by XML

Comment: you need dropdown list when you click a button right?

Comment: @harilalkm >>so where you added this butdin class? as document class ? >>>>Not at the same button.

Comment: could you share the fla? I couldn't get an idea about this. Or any screenshot or something. may be a screenshot will be helpfull. to know where you added that class

Comment: @harilalkm .sure/Moment

Comment: @harilalkm>>Can you help me here also [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31019216/please-help-sound12-button-does-not-disappear/31021182#31021182)

Comment: first sort out this issue.

Comment: @harilalkm  [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9BcYjTM8tPocmsteHZ4eVdGeU0/view?usp=sharing)  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9BcYjTM8tPocmsteHZ4eVdGeU0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @akmozo can you help me??

Comment: @FlashGirl I put an answer, take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try always to do easy, you don't need the `butdin` class, and you can insert directly your list in the Stage and then create the document class of your project :

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Main extends MovieClip {

        public function Main() {
            butdin.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btn_on_Press);
            list.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, list_on_Change);
        }
        private function btn_on_Press(e:MouseEvent): void {
            for (var i:int = 1; i < 8; i++){
                list.addItem ({ label: 'Track ' + i });
            }
        }
        private function list_on_Change(e:Event): void {
            trace('You selected : ' + e.target.selectedItem.label);
        }
    }

}
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: @FlashGirl What did you do exactly and what did you got ?

Comment: I load Example    https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9BcYjTM8tPoNllEWHhQdzFYWk0/view

Comment: I want a menu appears when you press the button
The list is open to me swf file>>

Comment: @FlashGirl I saw your example and I know what you want. Did you tried my answer and how ?

Answer (score 0):

The code you shared will not work any way. Because you created the button class wrongly.You are trying to add list and trying accessing the textfield .It's not possible anyway.Instead you could add a document class .

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;


    public class Main extends MovieClip {

        var list:List;
        public function Main() {
            butdin.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, sayit);
        }
        private function sayit (e:MouseEvent):void
        {


            list = new List();
            list.setSize (361,291);
            list.move (421, 254);
            //var i:uint;
            //for (i=1; i<8; i++)
            //{
            //list.addItem ( { label: "Track " + i } );
            //}
            list.addItem ( { label: "Track 1" } );//Opens swf file 1.swf in next frame on stage
            list.addItem ( { label: "Track 2" } );//Opens swf file 2.swf in next frame on stage
            list.addItem ( { label: "Track 3" } );
            list.addItem ( { label: "Track 4" } );
            list.addItem ( { label: "Track 5" } );
            list.addItem ( { label: "Track 6" } );
            list.addItem ( { label: "Track 7" } );

            addChild (list);
            list.addEventListener (Event.CHANGE, itemClick);


        }
        private  function itemClick ()
        {

            status_txt.text = "You selected: " + event.target.selectedItem.label;

        }
    }

}
```

Make sure all necessary packages imported and the button and the textfield has the instance name

Comment: what you mean by code not working? paste the error message

Comment: What you mean by nothing happened ? not even a error message or anything else. That's weird